# picturebox image text print is not clear

Tags: c#, winforms

```css
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            //e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            //e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
           // e.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
           // e.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            //e.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                
                   
                e.Graphics.DrawString("FIRST NAME" , myFont, Brushes.Black, 15, 90);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("MIDDLE NAME", font, Brushes.Black, 15, 105);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("LASTNAME", font, Brushes.Black, 15, 120);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("ADDRESS", font, Brushes.Black, 15, 135);
          e.Graphics.Flush();
          }

 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        //SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;           
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
        this.pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, x, y);
    }
```

print font word are not clear visible when i print picturebox image.
i want clear font (like microsoft word or excel print) letters visible when i printing images.
means good pixels
anybody suggest me?

Comment: Could you provide screenshots? There are dozens of issues, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7480150/1997232) or maybe `TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias` related.

Comment: i have not enough points to upload preview.

Comment: when i printing picturebox image text font must be very cleared but its not clear printed.like spreaded.

Comment: Did you set the dpi-resolution of the Graphics in PrintPage to something reasonable?

Comment: no i didn't set the dpi-resolution.how to set?

Comment: its very strange,people are not trying to help by voting up